# Set string[] values with a loop

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I'm looking for setting values of an array in C# this way :

```
        int i = 0;
        string[] faces = new string[104];

        for (i = 1; i < 104; i = i++)
        {
            faces[i] = i.ToString();
        }
```

However I think my code is missing something, but I don't have any error from visual studio, it's just looping without end. 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
i = i++
```

to this:

```
i++
```

`i++` is evaluated before the increment, so you're just setting `i` to `i`.

@jmcilhinney is also correct that you probably want to start at `0`, not `1`.

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop try to change:

```
for (i = 1; i < 104; i = i++)
```

to

```
for (i = 1; i < 104; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have reread how to write a `for` loop.  Don't declare a `for` loop counter outside the loop (it's possible but should not be done unless it's specifically needed, which should be rare) and don't make an assignment in the step.  Also, arrays are zero-based so why start `i` at 1?

```
string[] faces = new string[104];

for (var i = 0; i < 104; i++)
{
    faces[i] = i.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

`for (i = 1; i < 104; i = i++)`

to

`for (i = 0; i < 104; i++)`

Arrays start at index zero.
I'm not sure what `i=i++` will do but it won't be anything good.